# Windows Store App using Hub

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013, windows-store

I'm new with Windows Store apps. The most of the flows on the app will be done using the Hub component (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn449149.aspx). I'm using .NET Framework 4.5.1 and VS 2012.

I cannot find the Hub component and I don't have the Hub Sample project. I saw some people say that you need VS 2013 to use Hub (I'm using 2012), but why if the framework (4.5.1) is the same?

I've found this HubAppExtension project (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d8d9472b-7149-48cc-9e9b-dde5c67076d8) that works on VS2012, but although it looks similar, it doesn't use Hub and HubSection.

Should I really update to VS2013?

Thanks!

Comment: VS 2013 is required in order to create Windows 8.1 apps as it is. What do you mean ".NET Framework 8.1"? This does not exist.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 4.5.1. I fixed the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hub control is a  new control in Windows 8.1. So only in project which target is Windows 8.1, you can use Hub control. And Windows 8.1 project can only be created in Windows 8.1 OS and VS2013.